# fbchat searchForGroups doesn't show data

Tags: python

I'm working on fbchat in python and trying to get data from facebook group chats, however this implementation seems not working.

```
from fbchat import Client
client = Client('email', 'password')
group=client.searchForGroups('abc')
groups=group[0] #it will only prompt list index out of range as no data gathers
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @ellhe-blaster My problem is that my code doesn't provide any names or ID that I expect using client.searchForGroups( ), though I code it right & inputted necessary data. I used fbchat library. Do any have any solution?